# How to change the allowed formats in Import[...]?

Tags: import, data-acquisition

I want to read data from files with an unusual extension with the Import function. However, the following message appears:

[image: format error]

The data is well organized, when I rename the extension to ".dat" Mathematica reads it as expected. Can I change the allowed formats and include this ".data"?

Comment: Use the second argument of `Import` to specify the format?

Comment: ... i.e., `Import["proton"<>"Dauau1525-401.data", "Table"]`?

Comment: Don't rely on `Import` auto-detecting the format. Specify the format explicitly (2nd argument of `Import`).

Answer (score 1):

Use the second argument of `Import` to specify the format explicitly, e.g.,

```
Import["proton"<>"Dauau1525-401.data", "Table"]
```